# Mock ServiceProvider GetServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, moq

I'm having hard times to test a Factory that uses the .net core `ServiceProvider` to return a particular implementation given some logic.

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<IUrlProcessor>();
}
```

I'm partially have this with

```
var serviceProvider = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();
serviceProvider.Setup(m => m.GetService(typeof(IEnumerable<IUrlProcessor>)))
    .Returns(new List<IUrlProcessor>() {
        new PassthruProcessor()
    });
```

The `GetServices` seems to work but the `CreateScope` call just throws an exception. It is an extension method and I don't know what is the exact class I should mock so that the `CreateScope` call works.

Comment: `CreateScope` on `IServiceProvider` is, as you say, an extension method which resolves `IServiceScopeFactory` and calls `CreateScope` on that. You could either register an `IServiceScopeFactory` mock object.

Comment: FWIW, creating a `Mock<IServiceProvider>` that returns a `Mock<Anything>` is functionally the same as creating a real `ServiceProvider` that returns a mock. I suppose it's 6/.5 dozen.

Comment: This, in a nutshell, is why service-locator is an anti-pattern. When dependencies aren't injected, you can't abstract them, making your code harder to test.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In this scenario it probably doesn't help to create mocks that return more mocks. Your class depends on an `IServiceProvider`, and you need to call `CreateScope()`.

Mocking `IServiceProvider` to return another mock is functionally the same as using a *real* `ServiceProvider` and configuring it to return a mock. The difference is that if you use a real `ServiceProvider` you don't also have to mock `CreateScope`.

(I'm totally sidestepping questions about where and when to depend on the `IServiceProvider.`)

Here's a drastically simplified example:

The class that depends on an `IServiceProvider`:

```
public class ScopedFooFactory : IFooFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ScopedFooFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IFoo CreateFoo()
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            return scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFoo>();
        }
    }
}
```

...and some unit test code:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IFoo>(provider => fooMock.Object);
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var subject = new ScopedFooFactory(serviceProvider);
var foo = subject.CreateFoo();
Assert.AreSame(fooMock.Object, foo);
```

To me this is simpler and easier than creating a mock that returns more mocks.

Comment: I really like this approach when using .net core DI. Having that decoupled service collection made things like this so much more simpler to do than having to mock up IServiceProvider like before.

Comment: Oh I have one nit pick though, unrelated to the general answer. In your example class under test you return `IFoo` from within a using scope. Wouldn't that cause `IFoo` to also be disposed when the it goes out of scope upon return. It does not take away from your overall answer, was just curious on how you saw that flow with the using scope.

Comment: In this case `IFoo` isn't disposable, but even if it was, it won't get disposed in the unit test. As I wrote this answer I figured there were some details about the scope that I was glossing over. My suspicion is that for the purpose of the unit test, the scope doesn't matter as much as long as the needed object gets created.

Comment: I wasn't paying attention to that bit in the code before. Yes, that's a problem. You can't create a scope and then return a service out of the scope. Once the using statement goes out of scope, so will anything that was created from it. Essentially, you'll end up with a null reference.

Comment: I don't doubt you - I'm quite certain I'm the one who's missing something - but why does the test pass? ... I think that in this scenario as long as `IFoo` is the thing getting mocked, we're okay, because we don't really care whether it gets disposed. But I see the point. If the OP was actually doing this, the problem would be in the "real" use, not in the unit test. I'll fix my example.

Comment: I *think* is a weird situation causes by reference counts. See, the scope of this object is *actually* this test code, because that's where it was created. Even though it's being returned within a scope, the reference is back to the object in the main test code scope. Essentially, it's a weird edge case that wouldn't actually work in the wild.

Comment: My problem is that I'm narrowly addressing part of the problem, but I don't think I completely understand the entirety of what the OP is doing - in particular, where is the factory used, and what is done with the thing returned by the factory.

Comment: I agree that using a real `ServiceProvider` to register mock classes is the easiest way to use it. Thumbs up!